# Why do these lists function differently? (Python logic)

Tags: python, list, logic

I have stumbled across a way of creating a list that makes it less easy to work with. Let me show you my code, maybe you'll have an answer to what my functions do differntly to the lists.

```
sign = "-"

def createGamePlan_1(size, sign):
    gPlan = []
    for i in range(size):
        row = [sign]*size
        gPlan.append(row)
    return gPlan

def createGamePlan_2(size, sign):
    gPlan = []
    row = [sign]*size
    for i in range(size):
        gPlan.append(row)
    return gPlan

k = createGamePlan_1(3,sign)
k[0][0] = "X"

h = createGamePlan_2(3, sign)
h[0][0] = "X"

print(k,h)
```

The  output if I run this through the terminal would be

```
[["X","-","-"],["-","-","-"],["-","-","-"]]
```

and

```
[["X","-","-"],["X","-","-"],["X","-","-"]]
```

respectively.

Why?

Comment: The global variable **sign** is undefined, so the code doesn't run at all.

Comment: There you go! @Prune

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your code is invalid, the "why" you're running into is not affected (I presume that the k[0][0] and h[0][0] should both be `=0` instead of "X").

It has to do with the order of these three lines:

```
row = [sign]*size      // A
for i in range(size):  // B
gPlan.append(row)      // C
```

In the first case, you're doing BAC, which results in a new list every time you iterate. When i=0 you create one list and append that to the master list; when i=1 you create a new list, and so on and so forth. But in the second case you're doing ABC- you create one list and then append that same list multiple times. Since lists are mutable, this results in the one list changing, which appears to change all the lists (because they're all references to the same object in memory).

Answer (score 3):

in the `createGamePlan_1` you declare new `row` instance each time in loop,
but in the `createGamePlan_2` you declare `row` once time and added it multiple times, so you have a multiple refernce to one instance `row` in the second function.

Comment: Although the lists look the same, they cannot be manipulated in the same way? How is this possible, are the lists within the list of the second generated list linked to eachother in some way? How does the program know this when I try to change one of the elements of it?

Comment: once again in the second function you does not have three list you have three reference on the same list, which was declare before loop, hope it help you

Comment: glad to help you)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the same effect as in the first function you have to create each time a new copy of `row`.

```
def createGamePlan_2(size, sign):
    gPlan = []
    row = [sign]*size
    for i in range(size):
        gPlan.append( list( row ) ) # <==
    return gPlan
```

Otherwise the same reference will be appended to the list.

Pay attention to that in the first function inside the loop

```
for i in range(size):
    row = [sign]*size
```

a new object `row` is being created in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: I see, although I worked with Python in my recent course I never heard or learned about this "reference system". Where can I read more about it?

Comment: @SimpleProgrammer As far as I know all the Python documentation (for example for the version 3.6) can be found at https://docs.python.org/3.6/index.html